# What's the Microsoft DI equivalent of Castle.Windsor's UsingFactoryMethod

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Here is an example using Castle Windsor

```
Component.For<MultiInstanceFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod<MultiInstanceFactory>(k => t => (IEnumerable<object>)k.ResolveAll(t));
```

Where the **MultiInstanceFactory** is a delegate like so:

```
public delegate IEnumerable<object> MultiInstanceFactory(Type serviceType);
```

What would be the Microsoft DI equivalent of this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It is simply

```
serviceContainer.Add{Singleton|Transient|Scoped}<YourInterface>(sp => factoryHere);
```

You there are plenty of overloads.

[Here is the documentation for `AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-0))))

Comment: The ResolveAll is wat im after

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs a similar solution

```
services.AddTransient<MultiInstanceFactory>(serviceProvider => {
            var componentFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
            return (Type type) =>
            {
                var instances = serviceProvider.GetServices(type);
                return instances.Cast<object>();
            };
        });
```